# Is there an infinite set which is not countably infinite?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Need some help here guys, I am not sure how to proceed and answer this question as I think almost all infinite sets are countably infinite. I looked into some materials and notes of other universities, however I didnt find anything.

I checked with my professor, he told me that this proof is wrong. His comments were: "You would have to define the concept of cardinality. I think using Cantor sets and Dedekind cuts will lead you to a wrong direction- that's too difficult." Again, he mentioned, "As I said, I do not think you should bring in cardinality.  There is an example that can be obtained by using the definitions in the Notes (and contradiction). The cleverness is in coming up with the example."

Can someone help me in finding out which definition best suits for this problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: How about the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$? It is indeed infinite, but it is not countable.

Comment: $[0,1]$ ${}{}{}$

Comment: that's most certainly true, the set of real numbers is infinite but not countably infinite. However, is there any other examples that I can give? I was thinking of choosing a set where, (say x is the no of elements), and 0< x < 1. Then, bringing another number and using BWOC to show that its not countably infinite. Will that work?

Comment: @copper.hat: I was also thinking abt this, but I dont knw how to show this. Can you please show how its not countably infinite?

Comment: You will find this is most basic analysis textbooks.

Comment: Another example of a noncountable infinite set would be the set of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Your professor wants you to prove a statement about cardinality without using cardinality? That sounds strange. Are you sure you didn't misunderstand the statement? If it is indeed what you are supposed to do, what are the definitions of “countably infinite” and “infinite” in the mentioned notes?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ were countably infinite, then there would be a surjection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$.  However, the set $R=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n\notin f(n)\}$ is not in the range of $f$.  If it were, say if $f(i)=R$, then you would have the contradiction $i\in R\leftrightarrow i\notin R$.  Therefore, since there is no surjection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, it must be that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable.

There's nothing magical about $\mathbb N$ in that proof; the same argument could show that the power set of any countably infinite set is uncountable.  In fact, since the power set of any uncountable set is larger still, it would be more accurate to say that almost *no* infinite sets are countable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this, now it makes more sense to me. :)

Comment: I did this, however my prof told me that this proof needs to be based on proper topology. So this will not be acceptable. Is there a way to prove this by contradiction or contraposition?

Comment: As per my prof's view: This proof is not entirely accurate, he gave me some suggestions and recommendations which I posted in the question after editing it. Kindly go through that and help me on this. Appreciate your efforts though!!

Comment: In fact, this is just the proof of Cantor's theorem!

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun I don't know what to tell you about forming a simpler proof, since I don't know what your notes say.  I also don't know what he means when he says that my proof is wrong and that it has anything to do with Dedekind cuts.  He seems to be looking for some specific piece of "cleverness" that somehow determines uncountability without invoking the cardinality of the natural numbers.  Good luck!